# Redirecting the output sound to other audio devices in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, audio, osx-snow-leopard

Am using Mac OS X 10.6. I have a sound file, say "a.aiff" which i want to be redirected to Soundflower(not my default). afplay doesn't seem to provide --device flag which it used to support in earlier Mac versions I think. So any idea of what to do?

Comment: perhaps this might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563978/mac-force-another-application-to-use-a-specific-audio-device