# Mac: force another application to use a specific audio device

Tags: macos, audio

As the question already suggests,

I'm trying to figure out, if it's possible to force another Application/process to use a specific output device.

Not every Application has a dropdown menu to select which audio device should be used and therefore always uses the standard device.
But when running multiple applications this isn't always the desired solution.
Plus, even if the application has a device-selection, it's almost always buried deep within the menus.

I was thinking of something like faking the change of the standard-device (but only to one application)

Looking forward for you answers :)
Greetings

Comment: I'd recommend you also ask this question on Apple's Cocoa mailing list.

Comment: I'm not sure this belongs on StackOverflow. Unless I'm mistaken, you're not looking for how to do this programmatically, but more like how to do it in general. If that's the case, you'll want to take this question to superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Audio Hijack Pro](http://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijackpro/) already does this and it works great.  Rogue Amoeba are the experts at Mac OS X audio.